# I want to select non distinct records (select only duplicate records) in a oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

The following is the table (customer) and records are as follows:

```
CUSTID  CUSTNAME
100     ashwin
100     ashwin
200     adithyan
100     ashwin
300     aravind
300     aravind
300     aravind
```

I want the result to be like this (non distinct rows):

```
CUSTID  CUSTNAME
100     ashwin
100     ashwin
300     aravind
300     aravind
```

Comment: Want to select non distinct rows

Comment: Edit, not comment your own question

Comment: @Ashwinkumar Please mark the answer as answered if it has solved your problem. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> I want the result to be like this (non distinct rows):
>
> ```
> CUSTID  CUSTNAME
> 100     ashwin
> 100     ashwin
> 300     aravind
> 300     aravind
> ```

If I understand correctly, you want the rest of the duplicate rows. You could use the analytic **ROW_NUMBER**.

**Test case:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (CUSTID int, CUSTNAME varchar2(8));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
  3           VALUES (100, 'ashwin')
  4      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
  5           VALUES (100, 'ashwin')
  6      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
  7           VALUES (200, 'adithyan')
  8      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
  9           VALUES (100, 'ashwin')
 10      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
 11           VALUES (300, 'aravind')
 12      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
 13           VALUES (300, 'aravind')
 14      INTO t (CUSTID, CUSTNAME)
 15           VALUES (300, 'aravind')
 16  SELECT * FROM dual;

7 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Query using **ROW_NUMBER**

```
SQL> select custid, custname
  2  from (
  3    SELECT custid, custname,
  4           row_number() over (partition by custid order by custid) as rn
  5    from t
  6  )
  7  WHERE rn > 1
  8  order by custid;

    CUSTID CUSTNAME
---------- --------
       100 ashwin
       100 ashwin
       300 aravind
       300 aravind

SQL>
```

Gives your desired output.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar You're welcome! Please mark it as answered, it would help others too,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select custid, custname
from customer a where
exists (
select CUSTID, CUSTNAME, count(*)
from customer b
where a.custid = b.custid and a.custname = b.custname
group by CUSTID, CUSTNAME
having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: It gives result of all rows having duplicates. it selects all 3 rows of custid = 100. But i want only non distinct records, only 2 rows of custid = 100.